# how to remove part from the file name extension while downloading as excel

Tags: jquery

[working code JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/n9XRx/8/)

```
$( "#clickExcel" ).click(function() {  
  var dtltbl = $('#dtltbl').html();    
  window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent($('#dtltbl').html()));
});
```

when i click on download as excel ... i get .part along with the extension like `GhCRExp0.xls.part` how to download the file without the name .part .Just with the filename `GhCRExp0.xls`

Answer (score 0):

Which browser are You using? Meybe it's browser extension and something wrong there?

At my chrome it has no extension (it's just "downloaded").

Answer (score 0):

.part are unfinished downloads in chrome and maybe in other browsers too. Your fiddle words fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

This file will go away after the file is downloaded.  Is there an issue with waiting till the download is complete?